# Add attributes to layer

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

I'm trying to add a new attribute to a vector layer in my plugin. But it does not work.. Why?

```
selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
name = "newAttribute"
selectedLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(name,QVariant.Double)])            
self.selectedLayer.updateFields()
#or
self.selectedLayer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: You are first using the `selectedLayer` variable, then `self.selectedLayer`. Those are note the same variables. Is this intended? This may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: I have tried in different ways, do not get any!

Comment: Have you started editing by selectedLayer.startEditing()?

Comment: yes, i tried it

Comment: i think problem in this command selectedLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(name,QVariant.Double)]), becauce without it code goes down and work!

Comment: this code does work from console python, but only from it((

Answer (score 2):

This example work perfectly.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

lyr = iface.activeLayer()
lyr.startEditing()
provider = lyr.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("newAttribute", QVariant.Double)])
lyr.updateFields()
lyr.commitChanges()
```

Comment: but not in plugin

Comment: why not?this code work in a plugin or in qgis console.You probably need check your plugin.If you need examples of addatributes etc..Check this class https://github.com/All4Gis/instagram2qgis/blob/master/Insta2QgisDialog.py and the CreateShape method for example.

Comment: something wron in import block, mb?

Comment: @Евгения Сидоренко, within the plugin are you importing QVariant, from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

Answer (score 1):

I once had issues using the `currentIndex()` method (which might be unrelated to the issue you have). Instead, I use the `currentText()` method to identify the layer and add attribute fields:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentText()
selectedLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(selectedLayerIndex)[0]
name = "newAttribute"
selectedLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField(name, QVariant.Double) ] )            
selectedLayer.updateFields()
```